# Navigate to LWC from custom VF component w/outputLink

Tags: lightning-web-components, forcenavigatetourl

I need to update an existing custom VF component to navigate to an lwc instead of a VFP.
Can I make this work or should I be using a different pattern?

lwc  myLWC
vfp  myVFP

code

```
<apex:component >
<apex:outputLink onClick="navToMyVFP();" >Nav to MyVFP </apex:outputLink>

<script type="text/javascript">

function navToMyVFP() {
     sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,'/apex/myVFP', true);
}

</script>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your lighting web component in an Aura app. and call the app from Visualforce Page/Component.

I have created an app called `DemoApp.app` and have put the Lwc in it.
Then I used an anchor tag to navigate to the app.

```
<apex:component >
    <a href="/c/DemoApp.app"> go to lwc</a>
</apex:component>
```